# Calling a Generic Method using Lambda Expressions (and a Type only known at runtime)

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression, expression-trees

You can use [Lambda Expression Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) to represent a lambda as an expression.

How do you create a [Lambda Expression Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) representing a generic method call, if  you only know the type -that you use for the generic method signature- at runtime?

For example:

I want to create a [Lambda Expression Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) to call:
`public static TSource Last<TSource>( this IEnumerable<TSource> source )`

But I only know what `TSource` is at runtime.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  Which method on which object are you trying to create?  Do you want a reference to the Last generic method with a lambda expression?

Comment: @CasperOne: Hi Casper! a) I'm trying to create an instance of **TheObject**, that references to **TheMethod**. b) yes, I want to reference the last method with a lambda expression (lambda expression object I mean). Thanks : )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>> CreateLambda<T>()
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(
        typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "source");

    var call = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Last", new Type[] { typeof(T) }, source);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>>(call, source)
}
```

or

```
static LambdaExpression CreateLambda(Type type)
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(
        typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type), "source");

    var call = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Last", new Type[] { type }, source);

    return Expression.Lambda(call, source)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the question, but the code that dtb wrote could be written simply as:

```
class MyUtils {
  public static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>> CreateLambda<T>() { 
    return source => source.Last();
  }
}
```

The code in the sample by dtb is pretty much the same thing as what the C# compiler automatically generates for you from this lambda expression (compiled as expression tree, because the return type is `Expression`).

If you know the type at runtime, then you can either use the solution by dtb or you can invoke the `CreateLambda` method (above) using Reflection, which may be slower, but allows you to write the code in the lambda in the natural C#:

```
var createMeth = typeof(MyUtils).GetMethod("CreateLambda");
LambdaExpression l = createMeth.MakeGenericMethod(yourType).Invoke();
```

The nice thing about this approach is that the code in `CreateLambda` can be much more complicated, which would be really hard to do using expression trees explicitly.

Comment: Hi Tomas! I need to improve my programming communication skills I know, I know hahahha (but don't worry I'm working on it : ). I updated the question to represent what I really meant. Nice refactor! +1

Comment: @SDReyes: "at runtime" was the important point. You can still use the nice C# syntax for this though (without explicitly constructing expression trees). See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Tomas!, I agree with you. this approach let you implement easily complex lambdas inside the CreateLambda method (with just a performance tradeoff). I'm gonna use the dtb approach this time, because we are already using lots of expressions in the component we're working on, and I want to keep coherence among the code : ). but I'm going to be glad to implement yours in next scenarios too! Nice job Tomas! regards. SD