# Dynamic object: Get the sub generic type and provide it to another method

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic-dispatch

I've a method, which receive basically a `dynamic` object. This is due to a dynamic dispatching, and it is not the point to discuss of why I've a `dynamic` input here.

I know that this `dynamic` object represent a type  `ASpecialClass<T>` where T is unknown at the compilation time. Is there a way to extract the `T` type and give it to another method?

Like:

```
public void DoSomething(dynamic inputObject)//At this point, I know that it implements ASpecialClass<T>, but I don't know what is the T type
{
    extracType(InputObject);
    CallOtherMethod<With_the_extracted_Type>(inputObject);
}
```

There is two things here:

1. Is there a way to extract the type `T` of the parameter?
2. Is it possible to provide it back to another method, which is generic?

Thank you

Comment: I found these two answers already on SO - hope they help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362532/get-the-type-for-a-object-declared-dynamic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408120/how-to-call-generic-method-with-a-given-type-object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for question 1:

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericTypeArgument(dynamic inputObject)
    {
        var genType = inputObject.GetType();
        return genType.GetGenericArguments();
    }
```

Answer for question 2:

You need to use reflection to invoke generic method by passing the generic argument provided in Answer 1.
This has already been answered @ [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Comment: Thank you very much for the part 1 of the question, this is what I was looking for. Regarding the part 2, is there a way to avoid the reflection?

Comment: If you do not want to use reflection, you can always use Linq/Lambda Expressions. There's an answer for how to do this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850265/calling-a-generic-method-using-lambda-expressions-and-a-type-only-known-at-runt

Comment: Nice. Is it more efficient with lambda expression?

Comment: Yes lambda expression is more efficient than reflection. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803272/in-c-is-expression-api-better-than-reflection