# C# Expression tree that calls a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting, expression-trees

I have a generic method, with the following signature

```
 private static void ProcessItem<T>(int id) where T : BaseItem
```

And it gets called in the following way

```
ProcessItem<RedItem>(id: 2)
ProcessItem<BlueItem>(id: 7)
```

My issue is that I get the type of item on application start up via reflection as a `Type` object. 
So now I am looking for a way that I can construct an expression tree that will result in a lambda that calls this method with the appropriate type.

So I can do something like `lambda.Invoke(Type type, int id)`. And this will call something along the lines of `id => ProcessItem<type>(id)`

I found a similliar issue answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850366/5493420

However, the answer there shows how to instantiate a generic param of `IEnumerable<>` whereas I simply need to call my method, transforming the `Type` object into an actual `<Type>` parameter that my method can accept.

I am not exactly sure if this is even possible (converting a Type object into an actual type parameter), but would love to hear any suggestions on the topic.

PS: I am also willing to take a different approach (some reflection tricks maybe), as long as it doesn't affect performance by more than 10-20%

Comment: There is no way to write *efficient* expression which receives `Type` argument (the body has nit use reflection, which would make if worst than using reflection directly). Reflection or cached delegates (in some dictionary by `Type`) are the only options I see.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you expand on your idea for cached delgates. Do you mean that I have a predefined delagte with the correct type for each type object? Cause this will defeat the whole purpose of me doing this dynamically

Comment: Something like static `Dictionary<Type, Action<int>>` which you populate on demand for each `T`.

Comment: I think this answer is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: Yeah, I just tried this. Worked like magic. Weird how I did not find it before. Anyways, thank you and @nvoigt, who reported it as duplicate for helping me find it